# Select max value from table by category

Tags: sql, ms-access

| Bought X times | Name | Manufacturer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 19 | Олівець Faber-Castell, Castell 9000 F | FaberCastell |
| 14 | Набір акрилових глянцевих фарб C. Kreul El Greco 18 кольорів | Kreul |
| 10 | Набір акварельних фарб "Класика", ROSA Gallery, 12кол. | ROSA GROUP |
| 7 | Професійний акварельний пензлик Winsor & Newton - One Stroke | Winsor & Newton |
| 6 | Ластик електричний Derwent | Derwent |
| 6 | Гумка Koh-i-Noor 300/80 Слон | Koh-I-Noor |
| 5 | Набір маркерів Copic Sketch Set Skin Tones, 6 шт | Copic |
| 4 | Склейка для акварелі Derwent Inktense 300г 20л | Derwent |
| 4 | Пастель Van Gogh Royal Talens 60 кольорів | Royal Talens |
| 4 | Блокнот American Crafts Journal Studio | American Crafts |
| 3 | Кольорові олівці Prismacolor Premier 72 кольору в металевому пеналі | Prismacolor |

I have created a query which generates results like those above.
And, as you can see, there are two rows which contain Derwent as Manufacturer. I would like to leave only rows from each Manufacturer where "Bought X times" (a column, generated by Count()) is max. How can I do that?
As a result, I would like to get

| Bought X times | Name | Manufacturer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 19 | Олівець Faber-Castell, Castell 9000 F | FaberCastell |
| 14 | Набір акрилових глянцевих фарб C. Kreul El Greco 18 кольорів | Kreul |
| 10 | Набір акварельних фарб "Класика", ROSA Gallery, 12кол. | ROSA GROUP |
| 7 | Професійний акварельний пензлик Winsor & Newton - One Stroke | Winsor & Newton |
| 6 | Ластик електричний Derwent | Derwent |
| 6 | Гумка Koh-i-Noor 300/80 Слон | Koh-I-Noor |
| 5 | Набір маркерів Copic Sketch Set Skin Tones, 6 шт | Copic |
| 4 | Пастель Van Gogh Royal Talens 60 кольорів | Royal Talens |
| 4 | Блокнот American Crafts Journal Studio | American Crafts |
| 3 | Кольорові олівці Prismacolor Premier 72 кольору в металевому пеналі | Prismacolor |

Query:

```
SELECT Count(Goods.Contract) AS [Bought X times], Goods.Goods_name AS [Name], Producer.Company AS [Manufacturer]
FROM Producer INNER JOIN (Goods INNER JOIN [Goods-Check] ON Goods.Goods_code= [Goods-Check].Goods_code) ON Producer.Contract= Producer.Contract
GROUP BY Goods.Goods_name, Producer.Company
ORDER BY Count(Goods.Contract) DESC;
```

Comment: Please do not upload images, but both your query and the expected result as text.

Comment: Is your query stored as a MS Access query?

Comment: @SalmanA Yes, it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An old fashioned solution is to filter rows where another row with greater value does `not exists`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Query1 AS t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Query1 AS x
    WHERE x.Manufacturer = t.Manufacturer
    AND   x.[Bought X times] > t.[Bought X times]
)
```

This is standard SQL, not sure if it works in MS Access.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works :) Is there any way to execute everything in one query?